# autohide multiple rows in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel Workbook were:
If a cell in column "A" on sheet "selection" is empty then the same row on sheet "Print" is hidden.  If the cell in column "A" on sheet "selection" has a value then the same row on sheet "Print" is visible.

I have the code written to automatically auto-hide/un-hide the rows on change. It works great if I change one cell at a time in column "A" on sheet "selection".  When I select multiple cells in column "A" and delete the values, only the first cell in the selection auto-hides the row on sheet "Print". I would like all rows corresponding to my selection to be updated.  Ex. If I select A3:A7 on sheet “Selection” and delete the values, rows 3 thru 7 should be hidden on sheet “Print”.

Here is the code I have on sheet “Selection”:

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target.Column = 1 Then
        For Each aCell In Target.Cells
            ThisRow = Target.Row
            If aCell.Value = "" Then
                Worksheets("Print").Rows(ThisRow).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Else
                Worksheets("Print").Rows(ThisRow).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            End If
        Next
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    End Sub
```

I am using Excel 2013.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target.Column = 1 Then
        For Each cel In Target.Columns(1).Rows
            Worksheets("Print").Rows(cel.Row).EntireRow.Hidden = Len(cel.Value2) = 0
        Next
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are always calling the Target.row.  This will only grab the first row of the Target range.

Change this line:

```
ThisRow = Target.Row
```

to:

```
ThisRow = aCell.Row
```